# How to use JSOUP to get the data from website

Tags: android, web-scraping, jsoup

I want to get the 'Fixtures' data from this page: [Link] using jsoup but I have no clue of how to get the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Include Jsoup in gradle

   ```
   implementation "org.jsoup:jsoup:1.11.3"
   ```
2. Connect to page

   ```
   Document doc = Jsoup.connect('url').get();
   ```
3. Select and get the element by id or xpath...

   ```
   Elements el  = doc.getElementsByClass("col");
       for (int i = 0; i < el.size(); i++) {
           if (el.get(i).classNames().contains("col1")) {
               Log.d("EL", el.html());
           }
           if (el.get(i).classNames().contains("col2")) {
               Log.d("EL", el.html());
           }
           if (el.get(i).classNames().contains("col3")) {
               Log.d("EL", el.html());
           }
       }
   ```

p.s. You will need to handle asnyc call yourself `Jsoup.connect` will throw `NetworkOnMainThreadException` if you call it directly in activity.

Comment: I edited my question to show some of the data I would like to get. Can you give me a example or point me in the right direction? The page shows two lists of fixtures and i need to get them both, but I'm confused on how to get them both if they are named the 'same'

Comment: Does this help? - Look at pt. 3.